# Can't check 'Phone Audio' setting for a Bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth

Somehow, suddenly I can't hear phone calls with my Bluetooth headset - I don't know what happened.

I tried to check the *Phone Audio* option under the device's 'Use for' settings, but it is impossible! It can't be checked.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I found this fix/workaround: Go to Settings, then Bluetooth. Turn off the Bluetooth and the screen should show a link for the scanner settings. Click the link to turn off "Bluetooth scanning." Then it works...

I copied it from here: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/MotoG4thGen/thread-id/16482/page/4

Comment: I would upvote you a million times if I could. Been struggling with this but found nothing online.

Comment: You can also get to this setting directly by going to _Settings_ > _Location_ > _Menu_ > _Scanning_ > _Bluetooth scanning_

Comment: I have to go to Settings and search for "bluetooth" to find it, on my Pixel 2 running Android 9.  Big surprise to find screens that I can find no other way to reach!  Regardless, just turning Bluetooth off and on again fixed this for me.